# gdb with python extensions : return error after executing my convenience function

Tags: python, gdb

I'm trying to implement a convenience function in gdb using python extension. Currently my function is very simple and does not do anything :

```
import gdb
class ListLocalVars(gdb.Function):
    """listing local variables"""

    def __init__(self):
        super( ListLocalVars, self).__init__("local_vars")

    def invoke(self):
        return 

ListLocalVars()
```

When I invoke the function inside the gdb interpreter, I got the following error :

```
(gdb) call $local_vars()
 Python Exception <class 'TypeError'> Could not convert Python object:None.: 
 Error while executing Python code.
```

By the way, my gdb uses python 3.4.3

Any idea ?

Comment: In Py3 you can use a short form of super ([PEP 3135](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/)):`super().__init__("local_vars")`

Comment: Possibly `invoke` method should return something, not a `None` value.

Comment: @AndreyT Thanks, I try returning an intege and it works! However, is it possible to return more complex types, e.g.      `list`  ?

Comment: Not sure about that, but you can try cast list to [gdb.TYPE_CODE_ARRAY](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Types-In-Python.html#Types-In-Python). [Example](https://github.com/wiredtiger/dotfiles/blob/f015de079d83ccaade9dc8be74acfa6c44dce3e6/mjc/wtpg.py#L20) from github.

Comment: A gdb.Function should return a type that can be converted to a gdb.Value. See the documentation for [gdb.Value](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Values-From-Inferior.html#index-Value_002e_005f_005finit_005f_005f-1856) to see which Python types are supported.